# How to watch lectures in Adobe Connect app when I can't find Flash 11.2 for Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, adobe-flash

I want to watch prerecorded Adobe connect lectures on my Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1.

The problem: when I try to play them through a browser (I have tried Chrome, Firefox, Dolphin, and the default browser on android) and through the [Adobe Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.adobe.connectpro) app I downloaded from the Play Store, I'm told every time that:

> Adobe Connect requires Flash Player 11.2 or above.
>
> Adobe Connect requires the Flash Player plugin, version 11.2 or above.  Please download and install the Flash Player to continue.

I have successfully gotten Flash 11.1 on my phone, thanks to a tutorial I found through Google search using the Dolphin browser. Obviously, that is not 11.2. I did search Google on how to get 11.2 on Android but I could not find anything useful. From Adobe's official site it's not compatible with my device.

Specifically, I want to watch lectures like [COP1000 Lectures
Fall 2013](http://burtondsc.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/84306340/lectures_cop1000_fa13.htm) (but for the upcoming semester - same concept)

I  have even tried adding a link from that page to the Adobe connect app but with no luck.

If there is anyone who can help me in any way get access to these lectures on my phone that would be amazing. Even if it means finding a way to convert the lectures to an mp4 or other video format. (I tried searching that on Google too)

Comment: Hi! I've edited your question including the title(see if you can make it more catchy compared to original one :), removed some irrelevant stuff -- you know which one. Feel free to rollback if the edit is unjust, or [edit] the question furthermore, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Puffin Browser](https://www.puffinbrowser.com/). I'm able to watch the Adobe connect lectures for school (as mentioned in the post). Puffin seems pretty fast and impressive with flash.